# How to create a table of content for pdf viewer in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, intellij-idea, pdf-viewer

I'm working on an online learning platform. I've used ng2-pdf-viewer to display my lessons which are in pdf format obviously. I'm looking for a way to create a side bar menu on which the user can find all the different chapters of the lesson.
[LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XzTq.png)

I've thought about using page jumps to jump from one chapter to another as you click on its name on the side menu but that would be very unconvinient for me cause there will be quite alot of lessons and pdf files. I was looking for how the table of content thingy [THIS ONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03zpP.png) that you can find on any pdf file, was made but I didnt get anywhere. Any suggestions ?

Angular 2 + IntelliJ

Comment: that's right show the code

Comment: @RomanC  the code of my pdf viewer ?

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking, clarify the question.

Comment: @RomanC I want to create something similar to the bookmark on pdf adobe reader.

Comment: @Unity Have you done this?